# Is it possible to setup private endpoint service for Web Push?

Tags: web-push, progressive-web-apps

I am learning Web Push [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/), then success to build sample notification web app step by step, with [Push Companion](https://web-push-codelab.glitch.me//), now for server side, I am able to send msg to "fcm.googleapis.com", then any client which subscribe that endpoint(fcm.googleapis.com) can get the notification even web page is closed. That's great, but I am concerning with business case, for security reason, it is not possible to send sensitive data to open endpoint such as "fcm.googleapis.com" for company, so is it possible to setup private endpoint to handle message? If yes, for browser side, does 'subscribe' API support to specify endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the **standard** (W3C Push API), then the notification payload is sent encrypted to the browser push service (e.g. Firebase, Mozilla autopush, etc), so they cannot read the content. Also, you can even decide to send only a push signal to activate the service worker and then fetch the notification content from your own server.

However note that what I said above is true only if you use the standard. Firebase also offers a **proprietary SDK**: if you use their SDK to collect subscriptions or to send notifications, then they will able to collect additional information.

Basically, if you don't want to allow Firebase to see your contents, you need to collect subscriptions using your own code and store the endpoints on your own server. Then you can send the notifications with the encrypted payload from your server to Firebase.

As for changing the push service, only Firefox currently supports that (but it is experimental).

Comment: thanks for your clarify. Very disappointed that not possible to customize push service, because this is really amazing feature. What I am wonder is real-time notification: long-polling such as comet is not efficient, web-socket is also not possible due to security policy, timer inside javascript engine is really bad solution... And the nice feature with W3C  Push and Notification API is even web page is closed, as long as browser is running(service worker), then user is able to get notification.